# tqdm NameError: global name 'HTML' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, tqdm

I'm learning to use [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm). I made a very simple test case but met with `NameError`. The test case is as follows:

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

num = 100
bar = tqdm_notebook(total=num)
```

The file name is `b.py` and I run:

```
python b.py
```

The error happened and the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 4, in <module>
    bar = tqdm_notebook(total=num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tqdm/__init__.py", line 19, in tqdm_notebook
    return _tqdm_notebook(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tqdm/_tqdm_notebook.py", line 183, in __init__
    self.sp = self.status_printer(self.fp, self.total, self.desc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tqdm/_tqdm_notebook.py", line 104, in status_printer
    ptext = HTML()
NameError: global name 'HTML' is not defined
```

I thought it was because I did not install a package named `HTML`, so that I run

`sudo pip install HTML`

It did installed an `HTML` package. But the error remained the same when I run the test case again.

What's wrong with this example? Did I miss other packages? Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: `tqdm_notebook` is for use in an IPython/Jupyter environment only.  You do not appear to be running your code in such an environment.